# Disconnection because of Scaling-Up an Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Lets imagine that I am an Admin/software engineer on an online retail company (like Amazon). I have a WebApp running on an S1 instance:

```
S1
100 total ACU
1.75 GB memory
A-Series compute equivalent
```

One day I see that there is very high traffic being generated to our web site because it is holidays (eg. Christmas) and I decide to scale-Up the server (not scale-out) to the new instance size of P2V2:

```
P2V2
420 total ACU
7 GB memory
Dv2-Series compute equivalent
```

In one of the learning paths from MS ([Scale an App Service web app to efficiently meet demand with App Service scale up and scale out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/app-service-scale-up-scale-out/4-scale-up-a-web-app)) it states the following:

> Scaling up can cause an interruption in service to client apps running
> at the time. They might need to disconnect from the service and
> reconnect if the scale-up occurs during an active call to the web app.
> And new connections might be rejected until scaling finishes.

My question is the following. Can I somehow avoid such disconnections (interruptions to the service) in a Scale-Up situation? For example imagine the following scenario:

1. a customer orders some products (that had in his/her shopping cart).
2. Little before the disconnection, the service had done a payment charge to the credit card of the customer.
3. Interruption of the service occurred due to scaling-up after the credit card charge occurred and little bit before a final status update. As such, the system couldn't inform (update) the DB (or even add some data to a queue) that the payment occurred successfully.
4. Now, nobody knows that the order has been processed (charged) correctly and as such nobody will dispatch it - hurting the image of the company to the customer.

How could I avoid such situation? Is it possible that the scaling-up mechanism doesn't cold-shutdown the service in order to update the hardware but it waits for the connections or running processes to finish first?

Answer (score 1):

For your imagine scenarios, you can consider using scale out ([autoscale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/auto-scaling)) rather than scale up. Scale out makes the application continues running without interruption.

> **Horizontal scaling**, also called scaling out and in, means adding or
> removing instances of a resource. The application continues running
> **without interruption** as new resources are provisioned. When the
> provisioning process is complete, the solution is deployed on these
> additional resources. If demand drops, the additional resources can be
> shut down cleanly and deallocated.

Comment: Yes. But I am trying to understand if there is a solution in case someone scales up.

Comment: Sorry @EfthymiosKalyviotis, I'm afraid you cannot avoid the interruption when scales up.